# 'HelmetProvider' is not a valid JSX element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-helmet

I'm using typescript and react to develop dashboard. The code works fine in my laptop, but this error shows in pipeline, `'TypeScript error in App.tsx. HelmetProvider' is not a valid JSX element. Its instance type 'HelmetProvider' is not a valid JSX element.`
I tried all the solution found here but didn't work. I'm using nodejs version 16.4.2, react-helmet-async v 1.3.0, typescript version 4.4.2

Below is the code in App.tsx.

```
  import { Helmet, HelmetProvider } from "react-helmet-async";
  function App() {
  const content = useRoutes(routes);
  const { theme } = useTheme();
  // localStorage.removeItem("auth_session");
  const helmetContext = {};

  return (
    <HelmetProvider context={helmetContext}>
      {
        <Helmet
          titleTemplate="%s | Leelou Dashboard"
          defaultTitle="Leelou Admin Dashboard"
        />
      }
      <Provider store={store}>
        <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
          <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
            <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
              <MuiThemeProvider theme={createTheme(theme)}>
                <ThemeProvider theme={createTheme(theme)}>
                  <AuthProvider>{content}</AuthProvider>
                </ThemeProvider>
              </MuiThemeProvider>
            </StyledEngineProvider>
          </LocalizationProvider>
        </StylesProvider>
      </Provider>
    </HelmetProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try to ugprade `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` with latest versions